# Vue 3 refs behave differently if they are the property of an object

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

When using Vue 3's Composition API, I've noticed that inside a template refs behave differently when they are accessed as the property of an object. I think this is best summarized by [this example in the SFC Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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), but here's the key code (from a Single File Component):

```html
    <script>
    import { ref } from 'vue';
    export default {
      setup() {
        const wut = ref(false);
        const obj = { wut };
        return {
          wut,
          obj,
        };
      },
    };
    </script>
    
    <template>
      <!-- obj.wut - false -->
      <h3>obj.wut - {{ obj.wut }}</h3>
      <!-- !!obj.wut - true -->
      <h3>!!obj.wut - {{ !!obj.wut }}</h3>
      <!-- obj.wut.value - false -->
      <h3>obj.wut.value - {{ obj.wut.value }}</h3>
      <!-- !!obj.wut.value - false -->
      <h3>!!obj.wut.value - {{ !!obj.wut.value }}</h3>
      <!-- does display -->
      <h3 v-if="obj.wut">display logic for this: v-if="obj.wut"</h3>
      <!-- does not display -->
      <h3 v-if="!obj.wut">display logic for this: v-if="!obj.wut"</h3>
      <!-- typeof obj.wut - object -->
      <h3>typeof obj.wut - {{ typeof obj.wut }}</h3>
    </template>
```

Can anybody explain why it appears to treat the ref as an object in some cases and interpret its value in other cases? Is this a bug, or by design?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short Answer: this is **by design**.

Long answer:

Please check [Vue3 Guide -> Advanced Guides -> Reactivity -> Reactivity Fundamentals -> Ref unwrapping](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity-fundamentals.html#ref-unwrapping)

> Ref Unwrapping
>
> When a ref is returned as a property on the render context (the object returned from setup()) and accessed in the template, it automatically shallow unwraps the inner value. Only the nested ref will require `.value` in the template:

In your example **template**, the `obj.wut` is a ref object, the `wut` is an unwrapped primitive value (a Boolean)

Extras:

1. In your example, the `obj.wut` is rendered as `false` in the page, seems it is working without `.value`. That is because of a [`toDisplayString` function](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/blob/ccb6651b12af6d1b43e2391cef77fd0bb73e49bd/packages/shared/src/toDisplayString.ts#L21) in vue, it takes the ref object (`obj.wut`), it does `JSON.stringify` on the inner value of the ref object. If the value of `wut` is `a string` (`const wut = ref('a string');`), you will see extra double quotes around it in the rendered page, like `"a string"`
2. There is also another tip in the doc, you can wrap the object in a `reactive` (`const obj = reactive({ wut })`) to access the unwrapped value in the template.