# Vuejs 3 (Composition API) v-model render [object Object]

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I tried to create reusable/composable hooks in vuejs 3 called `useCounter`. The function return object `count` (ref) and `increment`. When I set `v-model.number="counter.count"` it will render [object Object], but for `v-model.number="count"` it render correctly

I increment `counter.count` from `App.vue` in `increment()` also works

App.vue

```js
<script setup>
import { ref, computed, unref } from 'vue'
import useCount from './useCount.js'

const count = ref(5)

const counter = useCount({
  initialCount: 5
})

const increment = () => {
  count.value++ // Added
  counter.count.value++ // Added
}

console.log("count", count)
console.log("counter.count", counter.count)
</script>

<template>
  <h1>{{ counter.count }}</h1>
  <input v-model.number="counter.count" />
  <button @click="counter.increment">
    Increment useCount
  </button>

  <h1>{{ count }}</h1>
  <input v-model.number="count" />
  <button @click="increment">
    Increment all
  </button>
</template>
```

useCounter.js

```js
import { ref } from 'vue'

const useCount = (props = {}) => {
  const count = ref(props.initialCount ?? 0)
  
  const increment = () => {
    count.value++
  }
  
  return {
    increment,
    count,
  }
}

export default useCount
```

Result: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZo5Z.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `{{ count }}` is [unwrapped automatically](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#ref-unwrapping-in-templates), and in `v-model` is treated as `v-model="{value:0}"`, so you could fix it by destructing the returned value from the composable hook :

```html
<script setup>
import { ref, computed, unref } from 'vue'
import useCount from './useCount.js'
const {count,increment} = useCount({
  initialCount: 5
})
</script>

<template>
  <h1>{{ count }}</h1>
  <input v-model.number="count" />
  <button @click="increment">
    Increment useCount
  </button>

</template>
```

**[DEMO](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)**

Comment: The reason is that refs are unwrapped when exposed to a template directly (defined as a var in script setup), this is mentioned in docs

Comment: @EstusFlask, thank you, But why it is unwrapped in `{{ counter.count }}` and not in `v-model`?

Comment: `{{ counter.count }}` interpolation syntax automatically unwraps refs, in addition to unwrapping top-level comp properties. In other cases refs are treated as is in a template, and v-model results in `<input :value="{ value: 0 }">`

Comment: Thanks, this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70339462/9905881 is similiar too